# Using variables within the WHERE clause in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql

I'm new to Oracle SQL Developer. I have a VFP background and I'm having a difficult time trying to use variables as I have done quite a few other applications. Define the variable, determine what the variable is (programmatically), then use the variable. I'm good with the first 2 but I cannot figure out how to use the variable. Create a procedure, write the select statement to a var string, output to a cursor? I've seen many examples but nothing I can use or I'm just not understanding the different concept. Here is the code I've started with.

```
declare
    v_mydate DATE;
begin
  select max(date_added) into v_mydate from TEST_TB;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(TO_CHAR(v_mydate)); -- checking to see if the variable has been assigned. It has

create table test_banks as
SELECT DISTINCT
    FIELD1,
    FIELD2,
  , DATE_APPEND
FROM TEST_TB
  WHERE DATE_ADDED=V_MYDATE
end;
```

Field1 and Field2 will have many distinct combinations. I want them all that have the max(date_added) value.

Comment: You can use DDL statement in PL/SQL blocks? No,not directly: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_using_ddl_create_index_table_plsql.htm

Comment: Unless you want to do this as an exercise, you could get the data like `SELECT DISTINCT field1, field2, date_append FROM TEST_TB(SELECT TRUNC(MAX(date_added)) FROM TEST_TB);`

Answer (score 0):

DDL is not allowed here.  DDL is the data definition language.  CREATE TABLE is a DDL statement.
    Try execute immediate, which is really inefficient.

```
declare
    v_mydate DATE;
begin
  select max(date_added) into v_mydate from TEST_TB;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(TO_CHAR(v_mydate)); -- checking to see if the variable has been assigned. It has

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
'create table test_banks as
SELECT DISTINCT
    FIELD1,
    FIELD2,
  , DATE_APPEND
FROM TEST_TB
  WHERE DATE_ADDED in (select max(date_added) from TEST_TB)';

end;
```

Comment: But the whole point is to use the variable. Wouldn't the answer then be `'...where date_added = date ''' || to_char( v_mydate, 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) || ''';';`

Answer (score 0):

You need not use PLSQL to do this task,You can just create a view like the below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_TEST_BANKS 
AS SELECT DISTINCT field1, field2, date_append 
FROM TEST_TB where date_added=(SELECT TRUNC(MAX(date_added)) FROM TEST_TB)
```

or if you want to test the use of variables in WHERE clause you can try the below

```
    declare
          v_mydate DATE;
    begin
      select max(date_added) into v_mydate from TEST_TB;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(TO_CHAR(v_mydate)); -- checking to see if the variable has been assigned. It has

      FOR REC in (SELECT DISTINCT FIELD1, FIELD2,, DATE_APPEND
                    FROM TEST_TB
                   WHERE DATE_ADDED = V_MYDATE) LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('field1 ' || rec.field1);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('field2 ' || rec.field2);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('date_append ' || rec.date_append);
      END LOOP;
    end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the input all. I'm aware of how to get the value directly within a query, my question is more about how to use variables once they have been defined and a value stored to them. It appears that in order to use a variable to generate an output (create table based on data pulled by the variable) that the code needs to be a Procedure instead of just command lines within a worksheet?